What type of transmitter to use for a magic wand?
I'd like to mount a transmitter on a Harry Potter style wand. Then place a sensor in front of it (range 3-4m (couch to TV range)) to detect simple movements like upwards, downwards sideways.
What's the right technology to use for something like this?

Why would you need a transmitter? Just point a webcam from the TV to couch and use some computer vision tool to undersrand the movements of the wand? There are several different ways how to detect the movement. Do you actually want a transmitter, and what would it transmit?

@Justme I'm considering the cv option as well. Part of the reason to use a sensor was to learn to program a new peripheral/protocol, and to avoid other challenges like lighting conditions. I thought a small standalone transmitter like an IR bulb would be easier to mount on the wand and leave the receiver and the MCU setup on the tv. I'm a noob, so I'm probably way off. I'm open to any suggestions.

@kovac It's just random guesses, then. We don't really know much and there are too many possibilities. Shrink the problem to help manage the range. I can't answer about the right technology without the problem being quite specific. And even then, I'd likely be unsure. To vague, right now. Let me suggest something: Use a quad IR detector arranged at 45-degrees vs vertical/horizontal, facing the couch, in a telescope tube. Along the tube somewhere place a baffle with a pinhole. Use an IR emitter at the tip of the wand. Think about what this does and does not do for you.

Maybe something like this

The cost-efficient, and hobbyist-achievable, way to do that is probably not to put a transmitter, motion sensor, and detection logic in a tiny wand.
Instead, mount a small LED with a small rechargeable battery on that wand (it could be infrared!), and just use a webcam to look for a bright dot and write a bit of software (for a PC style computer or an embedded linux board) to detect the presence, and if present for multiple video frames in succession, record and analyze the trajectory of the dot. Fairly common thing, a bit like hand-writing deciphering for these old PDAs, afterwards. There's a lot of articles on that.

You can blink the LED at a known frequency to help with spurious signal rejection, too.
